# Cassandra: Strategy for performing transformations on existing tables

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm working on a project where I need to join several Cassandra tables and store the result into another Cassandra table.

From my understanding , the recommended approach is to use Apache Spark for performing such transformations (using RDDs and/or Datasets) . Unfortunately, we cannot use this framework in our project.

What would be an optimal strategy of performing joins on Cassandra tables ? Each table has several millions of entries.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra does not support joins but you can optimise you data modelling with your application code. Apache spark is the one of the solution also.

Comment: I am aware that Cassandra does not support joins.  I know that Apache Spark is the recommended solution, however I cannot use it in this project. 

What other options would you recommend?